# Solr - return all groups that have certain value within group

Tags: solr

I've got a number of products with options - let's say:

product `A` has options `a`, `b` and `c`; product `B` has options `b`, `c`.

In my Solr document these products are stored as: `A:a`, `A:b`, `A:c`, `B:b`, `B:c` (so for this situation I've 5 products stored in Solr). I'm grouping these products (so I've two groups - `A` and `B`).

How, for given model, can I retrieve **all groups** that have a certain option within the group? (if searching for product with option `a` it should return the group `A`, with products `A:a`, `A:b`, `A:c`).

I can't do it using `q`, as it will restrict the results set to only those products that have given option (so, in this case, if I do `q=field:a`, I'll get group `A` with result `A:a` and no other results). Can't use `group.query` as it returns only one group of results that match given query (if it returned all results I think this would be what I'm looking for).

Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index the items, you can define a child - for solr block join queries.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers

You can use the block join query to find children of certain parents, or parents of certain children.

To quote from the documentation

Block Join Parent Query Parser

This parser takes a query that matches child documents and returns their parents. The syntax for this parser is similar: q={!parent which=}. Again the parameter The parameter allParents is a filter that matches only parent documents; here you would define the field and value that you used to identify a document as a parent. The parameter someChildren is a query that matches some or all of the child documents. Note that the query for someChildren should match only child documents or you may get an exception.

Comment: This is certainly a solution, however it would require me to reindex my documents. I'll keep the question open for time being, in case there's another way (unlikely), but it's good to know Solr allows for this.